# Is it possible to build a camera + upload pic app using Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, camera, extjs

I need to develop a mobile app that is capable of using the device's camera to take a shot. Then it should be able to upload that photo to the server for display on the website front end. This paradigm would be similar to most photo-sharing social sites, like Instagram.

My question is if this is possible using the Sencha Touch 2 framework. Even if possible, is this a recommended approach? Would it be preferable to use another framework or develop this as native app using iOS SDK?

If you have any code to point to as an example it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first anwser is yes. Here are the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.Camera

I've done the above using Titanium, Native iOS and JS/HTML5. The functionality you are after is a simple and classic one, it will work in most frameworks. If you're not familiare with Objective-C, another "simpler" framework sounds good. If you think Sencha looks cool, try it out :) I haven't myself used it framework.

Comment: thanks Jens - based on the Sencha docs, I'm not sure it can alone do the job - does it need to interface somehow with phonegap?

Comment: Found something called NimbleKit: http://www.sencha.com/learn/enhancing-ios-sencha-touch-apps-with-nimblekit-pt-ii/

Comment: thanks a lot Jens - if you come across more like this in the future, please feel free to post here in the comments as I check SO quite often